# Cfsearch in combination of documents and indexed query data?

Tags: coldfusion, solr, verity, cfsearch

I have an application which stores all kind of data about people.
The current cfsearch functionality (in Verity) includes searching documents that are attached to these people.

If i have 2 documents attached to 1 person, 1 with say ABC in it and the other with XYZ in it, my ideal searchresult for "ABC AND XYZ" would return the 1 person. But as both 'words' are indexed in different documents, the standard behaviour is not to return any result from the cfsearch, because the combination doesnt exist in any of the 2 documents.

Is there any way to combine indexed documents and/or query data in a way that the search is executed in the combination of relevant docs and data? 
In my application that would mean that i could index all documents and data regarding people and have an intelligent 'global' search to find the right person.

ADDED: That also means that if i have one person with several documents attached to it (and maybe some additional indexed query-data) that from a search-point-of-view i would like to treat all that data 'as one'. Ie. if i have document1 with BREAD in it and document2 of the same person with BUTTER in it, ideally the search for BREAD AND BUTTER would result in a pointer to that person. (and ofcourse the normal searchindex doesnt find any matches because neither of the two documents contain both words.

any pointers and help very much appreciated! (should Solr offer new possibilities in comparison to Verity, no problem!)

thanks!

Bart

Answer (score 0):

Actually, documentation explains this pretty good.

I suppose you'll need "internet" search type. Attribute **type** [Used to specify the parser that Verity uses to process the criteria.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_r-s_13.html).

All available options explained in [Using Verity Search Expressions](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/indexSearch02_1.html#1160419) section, with nice examples.

Comment: hi - thnx for your pointer, but ofcourse i have been going through the docs intensively already. It seems (and thats logical aswell) that the search returns pointers to specific documents and pages. What i'm trying to accomplish is finding "groups' of indexed documents and data.
From what i see (or dont see :-) ) this is not so straight forward as i thought it might be. 
Any additional thoughts?

Comment: Think you should provide more technical details. How would search engine know such specific information about your website entities (groups/persons)? It's not really clear how do you link documents to the persons, but you can try to do the QoQ to filter out duplicates from search results, if this is your problem.

Comment: Sergi, i guess 'telling the searchengine' about the entities (persons) can now only be done by using the Custom1-4 attributes, which i use to store the personID in.
It would be great to have some kind of way to group/combine separate entities (indexed documents) into logical groups (and have those returned by a search), but i get the strong feeling that i'm looking for functionality that just can't be realized.

Comment: Can't be using pure Verity -- that's what I mean with "specific information", but you can search by all terms (that's what "internet" type does, if I remember correctly, or in any other applicable way, up to the separate searches per word) and process the results with your code.

Comment: will the "internet" type not search in the same indexed records? Or would i need to index the documents in a totally different way for them to be seen as 'one' logical databundle? I just cant find anything related to this specific kind of 'problem/situation'